# DateTime.Now behaviour when running as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, timezone

**Scenario:**

I have access to one user inside a server with multiple users (Windows Server 2019).
I want to get the Date/Time that my user would display on the clock when its logged on.
This user is currently configured with a south america timezone (UTC Offset -3 hours).

**The Problem:**

Im using DateTime.Now, because i want it to calculate the timezone configured, and give me the user's clock DateTime. But for some reason, when running as a windows service, it returns the UTC DateTime, even if the service is configured to be logged on as my user.
It works fine when running as a console application.

**What i tried:**

- Configuring the windows service to logon as my user (on the properties of the service), and restarting it.
- Running System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
  and Environment.UserName to verify that it is running as my user.
  Shows it correctly.
- TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id shows me the wrong timezone when running as a
  service (UTC).
- Clearing CultureInfo cache (CultureInfo.ClearCachedData)
- Checked Date/Time configurations in control panel.
- Running the code as a console application, in this case, it works
  fine, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id show the south america timezone and i get
  the clock's date/time (UTC -3 Hours).

So it seems to be some missing configuration to the service or windows, but i can't find what it is.

I want to understand what makes DateTime.Now return different values when its running as a windows service compared to when its running as a console application.

Comment: *"i want it to calculate the timezone configured"* - You can't. A time zone is far more than just a time offset. There is no 1:1 mapping for time offsets to time zones.

Comment: I just want the user's clock datetime. I want to understand where's the difference between  the return when running as a console application and as a windows service

Comment: How does the user interact with your service? The client-side code is the only place where you'll be able to  find the client's time zone ID, unless you store it in your application data by some other means.

Comment: its a background process, i just need the server's datetime to save some logs. So if i login the user configured on the windows service, i can just look at the clock and know it is in sync with the windows service process running DateTime.Now.

Comment: Is the service running on a remote server that has the same user account configured or are you running both the service and the console on your local machine?

Comment: im using windows remote desktop (mtsc.exe) to login on the server with my account. Then i install the service, configure the same user to run the service and restart it. Now my service gives me the UTC time, which is not the same as the time i see on the clock. But if i run the same code as a console application on this user, i get the clock's time (UTC -3).

Comment: Try to call LoadUserProfile in the service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilew and this for c# interop https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/userenv.loaduserprofile

Comment: If you already know what the time zone of the server is, you can simply add the hours in UTC time to get the exact value. For example, `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offsetHours);` will give a local time. Why to rely on the system if you already know which time zone you want the value to be calculated in?!?

Comment: What if he changes the timezone? I know what the timezone is on this user only. It will be installed on other machines that i dont know what the timezone will be. I dont have access to the server now, i will be doing more tests this week, since i can't reproduce this behaviour on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Servers always (or at least, should) run in the UTC 'timezone'.  Any time you store a date/time, it should be in UTC.  The only place that a DateTime is 'local' time, is when you are displaying it to or accepting it from, the user, because that is the only place you know HOW to display it.

A service doesn't have a UI, so it doesn't know the timezone of the user, because there isn't one.

When a .NET program starts, it finds out the timezone of the 'user' that ran the code, and saves that offset, so that whenever you call `DateTime.Now`, the program actually called `DateTime.UtcNow`, and adds on the offset for that timezone (which could be negative). There is NO WAY to change this once the program has started, you will have to do any conversions manually.  In the case of a service, it runs under the 'systemservice' user which is probably a UTC user, so `DateTime.Now == DateTime.UtcNow`.

So, to fix your problem, the UI that reads and writes to your service, needs to use the timezone and culture of the user that ran the UI, so it can convert any UTC date/times into the correct offset and format for that user.  This should NOT happen in the service, but in the UI that you create OUTSIDE the service.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but shouldn't the service run under the user configured on the Log On tab of its properties instead of systemservice? It shows the user configured if i call System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name when running as a service.

Comment: Hi.  This is only partially correct.  A Windows user doesn't have a time zone.  The time zone setting is for the entire system.  The only edge case is when using Windows Terminal Services and enabling Time Zone Redirection - which I can't tell from the OP's description if they are doing or not.  Also, the comment "There is NO WAY to change..." is incorrect.  One can call `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` to clear the system local time zone that .NET read from the OS on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I myself never coded an windows service application, but the DateTime structure includes an object for reading the computers UTC time:

> `DateTime.UtcNow`
> An object whose value is the current UTC date and time.

This gets the time of the computer in the UTC time zone.

You can then try to use:

> `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` An object whose Kind property is Local, and whose value is the local
> time equivalent to the value of the current DateTime object, or
> MaxValue if the converted value is too large to be represented by a
> DateTime object, or MinValue if the converted value is too small to be
> represented as a DateTime object.

Hope this helps, if this isn't the solution, try researching more about the DateTime structure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTimeOffset.Now
```

A DateTimeOffset object whose date and time is the current local time and whose offset is the local time zone's offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime.Now` returns the local time as per the timezone the machine where the code is running, is configured to be in. When you run a program on your machine, you get the time in your local timezone and all is well. On another machine, such as a server, the configured timezone in the OS (e.g. Windows) can be different, and `DateTime.Now` will return a different value as a result.

Whenever you work on any software which does not interact with the user, you should do all your date and time processing in UTC. To get the current UTC time, use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Then, when either outputting the time to the user, or allowing the user to input a time, you have to convert it from UTC to local and back, as appropriate. If you have a Windows application, like WinForms or WPF, you can get the current timezone using `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`. Then use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` to convert from UTC to local and back.